# In a bash script, how can I tell if the script is running under Ubuntu pure or in Linux subsystem for Windows?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a bash script (an end-to-end integration test for a software project) and at runtime I would like to know if the system is a pure Ubuntu installation, a MacOS installation, or bash running in the Windows subsystem for Linux? How can I do that?

Comment: Answer on [so], see [bash - How to check if running in Cygwin, Mac or Linux? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466166/how-to-check-if-running-in-cygwin-mac-or-linux/18790824)

Comment: None of the answers on that page seem to deal with the case of bash running in the windows subsystem for linux. When I run uname I get 'Linux'

Comment: That's because it is effectively Linux. WSL is a Linux emulator.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53998402/8928481

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` or the contents of the file `/etc/issue` in each of this systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the current running kernel with `uname -r`. In WSL it will be suffixed by "-Microsoft", ex: 4.4.0-17763-Microsoft (debian WSL). In Linux it would look like "4.19.42-v7+" and in macOS it has a darwin designator.

For example:

```
if uname -r | grep -q "Microsoft"
then
    do something
fi
```

See `uname --help` for more options.